# Difference between persist(MEMORY_ONLY) and cache()

Tags: apache-spark

I know the difference between cache and persist that persist has many storage levels. But what's the difference between cache() and persist(MEMORY_ONLY)? Both seem to do the same job. Is there any internal difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

`cache()` default to [`MEMORY_AND_DISK`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.cache), while `persist(MEMORY_ONLY)` is obviously `MEMORY_ONLY` only